# How to elegantly avoid duplication of code when < changes to >?

Tags: c++

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
template<typename TIterator>
TIterator findMaximalPosition(TIterator begin, TIterator end)
{
    TIterator result(begin);
    for (TIterator it = begin + 1; it != end; ++it)
    {
        if ((*it)->value > (*result)->value) // Here I just need to change to "<"
            result = it;                     // to get a findMinimalPosition
    }
    return result;
}

template<typename TIterator>
TIterator findMinimalPosition(TIterator begin, TIterator end)
{
    // almost the same
}
```

This is just a simplified example. My code is full of places where two functions are the same except for a `<` or `>` sign or whether `++` or `--` should be used.

My question is:

Is there a method how to reduce this duplication in code without

1. Destroying the readability
2. Decreasing the performance
   ?

I was thinking of using a pointer to an operator (either `<` or `>`) as a template parameter. This should not decrease performance, since the pointer would be a compile time constant. Is there some better or generally used way?

EDIT:

So what I did based on the answers was to implement:

```
template <typename TIterator, typename TComparison>
TIterator findExtremalPosition(TIterator begin, TIterator end, 
                               TComparison comparison);
```

and then just call:

```
return findExtremalPosition(begin, end, std::less<double>());
```

and

```
return findExtremalPosition(begin, end, std::greater<double>());
```

I hope this is what you meant. I suppose that after some struggling similar solution can be done for `++` and `--` operators.

Comment: See [`max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: Thank you, the problem is however that I get this situation a lot, and there are cases where a standard algorithm will not do the job. Also what do you mean by "=="?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: ... still, see `max_element`. Even if you cannot use it, it has the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make a general function that takes a predicate and use `std::greater` and `std::less` as argument to that function for the given type to implement `findMaximalPosition` and `findMinimalPosition` respectively.

Comment: Correct solution. Functors are typically more efficient than function pointers because they're inlined.

Comment: @MSalters For simple things like this, the compiler should be able to inline the versions with a pointer to a function as well.

Answer (score 1):

As sugested by [Ivaylo Strandjev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812912/ivaylo-strandjev), one possible solution is to use predicates.

So, if you change your function to work with predicates...

```
typename std::vector<int> vec;

template<typename TIterator, bool (*Predicate)(const TIterator &, const TIterator &)>
TIterator findPosition(TIterator begin, TIterator end)
{
    TIterator result(begin);
    for (TIterator it = begin + 1; it != end; ++it)
    {
        if (Predicate(it, result))
            result = it;
    }
    return result;
}
```

... and then, you define some predicates that helps you to achieve your goal...

```
bool lesser(const vec::iterator &a, const vec::iterator &b)
{
    return (*a) < (*b);
}

bool greater(const vec::iterator &a, const vec::iterator &b)
{
    return (*a) > (*b);
}
```

... then you would be able to do this:

```
vec::iterator min = findPosition<typename vec::iterator, lesser>(v.begin(), v.end());
vec::iterator max = findPosition<typename vec::iterator, greater>(v.begin(), v.end());
```

The advantage is to provide any function you would found useful, not only the ones to check if an element is greater or smaller than other:

```
bool weird(const vec::iterator &a, const vec::iterator &b)
{
    return ((*a) | (*b)) & 0x4;
}

vec::iterator weird = findPosition<typename vec::iterator, weird>(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Example [here](http://ideone.com/JQV1Nd).

But before do this effort, check if the [Algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) has already did the job.

I think that it looks pretty neat and simple.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Usually the predicate isn't taken as a template argument, just another parameter.

Comment: @GManNickG good point! now that you mention it, I don't know why I have used it as a parameter template :O